# Fill canvas with dots

Tags: android, android-canvas

There are many posts how to draw a dotted/dashed line or draw a border around circle. but I cannot find any information how to **fill** it. For example with `DashPathEffect` one can draw a stroke.

Is there any simple tool android provides similar to JS `createPattern()` ?

Comment: Can you post a image like what you want?

Comment: @meditat something like this https://codepen.io/icebob/pen/JYoQZg the dots that are on the background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [`BitmapShader`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapShader), which will allow you to create patterns. You can use it like this:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
Shader shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
paint.setShader(shader);
```

Then you use `paint` to draw on the canvas, and it will be filled with the specified pattern from the bitmap.

Comment: @AkakiGabisonia Yes, lots of ways. `Bitmap` documentation is a great starting point.